# Parse Cloud -- How to update column based on matching column in another table?

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform, cloud

In Parse, I am only able to segment off the `Installation` table to send push notifications to specific number of users. So, I have created a column called `sendPush` in the `Installation` table, which I will use to segment when sending the push notifications.

I want to set the new column to true, whenever the email is matched in another table - `SendPushTo`.

These are the two tables (with attributes):

**Installation** (email, sendPush)

**SendPushTo** (email)

I want to simply set  `sendPush` (boolean type) to true if the email is in the `SendPushTo` table. In other words, set `sendPush` to true for email addresses that are in both tables.

I have attempted to write Parse Cloud Code to solve this problem, but for some reason it only updates 9 values.

Here is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setPushVals", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var sendPushTo = Parse.Object.extend("SendPushTo"); //table with emails
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(sendPushTo);
    pushQuery.limit(1000);
    var columnName = "sendPush";

    var recipientQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    recipientQuery.limit(1000);
    recipientQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("email", "email", pushQuery);

    recipientQuery.find({
        success: function(recipients) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
               var recipient = recipients[i];
               recipient.set(columnName, true);
               recipient.save ();
            }
            response.success("Updated " + recipients.length + "-many recipients");
        },
        error:function (error)
        {
            response.error("Failed to save vote. Error=" + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

If I re-run the code with this line added (right before calling find):

```
recipientQuery.notEqualTo(columnName, true);
```

...it updates the next 9 rows. So, the solution I am currently using, is to call the function (`setPushVals`) a multiple number of times (each time 9 more rows are set to true) until all of the rows are updated.

Also, I should note that the `recipients.length` always comes out as the current number of rows to update, but when I check Parse, only 9 are updated.

Is there an easier way to do this and why does it only update nine rows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why does it only update nine rows?

It's possible that you are [timing out](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource). From the Parse Cloud Code Guide:

> Cloud functions will be killed after 15 seconds of wall clock time... 
>   If you need additional time to perform operations in Cloud Code, consider using a [background job](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs).

---

Edit:

I should also point out that this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
    var recipient = recipients[i];
    recipient.set(columnName, true);
    recipient.save ();
}
response.success("Updated " + recipients.length + "-many recipients");
```

does not wait for the saves to complete. It loops through all the recipients and saves them each in the background. By the time the looping code is done, it calls `response.success(...)` which halts any further execution.

You should use [promises](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel) to run the save code in parallel and wait for all the tasks to complete, then you can call success/failure afterwards. For example your code could be:

```
recipientQuery.find().then(function(recipients) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        var recipient = recipients[i];
        recipient.set(columnName, true);
        promises.push(recipient.save ());
    });
    // Return a new promise that is resolved when all of the saves are  finished.
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}).then(function() {
    response.success(...);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error.message);
});
```

Comment: I do not think so, because the success message is always printed within 1 or 2 seconds. So, all of the code is being executed within 1 or 2 seconds. Definitely not more than 15 seconds. 

Could there be another time out that I am hitting?

Comment: You are absolutely right! I do have another question, though. What if there are more than a 1000 rows to update? How can update more than 1000? Thanks!

Comment: Either use a background job with [each](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#each) which only works in a background job. Or you can run multiple queries for 1000 each, and offset by 1000 each time.